# Opening a file with NSDocument-based app

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I'm trying to open a file, and I'm currently implementing

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

from within the NSDocument subclass. ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocument/1515198-readfromdata?language=objc) for above method)

For some reason, typeName is returning as a string "DocumentType". I thought its supposed to be the file extension of the file opened, but now I'm not sure.

Is this correct? How do I error check to make sure the user didn't open an unsupported file type? Thanks

Comment: I just realized that DocumentType is a default string in the Info.plist. My question is, if my app only opens things like jpg, png, do I need to customize my own DocumentType?

Comment: Does your `NSDocument` subclass represent a jpg/png file or do you save your documents in a custom format?

Comment: Neither, am I using NSDocument based app incorrectly in this case?